# jQuery animate Scrolltop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to scroll the page to a particular div on button click using jquery. Even though I'm not getting an error in the js console, the page is not scrolling to the the desired div. I even tried adding the jquery js file before & after the  tag but still the problem persists.

Check code:

```js
$("#search_btn_home").click(function() {
  console.log("Inside existing click function of search");
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#friendstoreline").offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image: url('images/bluebackground.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat; min-height: 500px">
  <div id="search_btn_home">
    Click
  </div><br />
  <div id="friendstoreline"><strong>The Friend Store</strong></div><br />
</div>
```

Even though the above message is being printed in the console with no errors, the page is not scrolling to the required div. Please Help..

Comment: Where is the `#search_btn_home` element? Do you see the `console.log` being output?

Comment: I added `#search_btn_home` in your code, and its working absolutely fine.

Comment: @nashcheez My code was working previously but now for some reason it has stopped working..can't figure out why..

Comment: It's working for me in the example you provided...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you close this question, because if everything is working fine then this is not a question at all.

Comment: @nashcheez I don't have that ability unfortunately. I can only close if it's a duplicate, which I don't want to do as there must be some other underlying issue. If the OP can give more detail this could yet be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working after adding button with id `#search_btn_home`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/x8je6y92/)

```js
$("#search_btn_home").click(function() {
  console.log("Inside existing click function of search");
  $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#friendstoreline").offset().top
    },
    'slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="min-height:500px">
  <br />
  <div id="friendstoreline"><strong>The Friend Store</strong></div>
  <br />
</div>
<button id="search_btn_home">CLICK

</button>
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of your original code. From what you have provided this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run your code in a codepen and it worked.
Maybe your view isn't overflowing, so the page cannot scroll to the desired object (because it's already on the page).

All I've changed at your code is include the missing button

`<button id="search_btn_home">Scroll</button>`

Take a look at [my codepen](https://codepen.io/xjeeh/pen/oZoQxK) and check if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<div id="menu"><button class="page-scroll" href="#friendstoreline"></button></div>
<div style="background-image: url('images/bluebackground.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat;min-height:500px">
<br />
<div id="friendstoreline"><strong>The Friend Store</strong></div>
<br />
```